# How to reset a value stored in SQLAlchemy during query access?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a SQLAlchemy db.Model class with a variable whose value I would like to update/reset during query access?

```
import datettime as dt

class MyEventCounter(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title =  db.Column(db.String(128))
    daily_counter = db.Column(db.Integer, default=0)
    last_updated_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False,
    default=dt.datetime.utcnow)
```

The daily_counter increases throughout the day, but updates/resets the following day.

Is there a way to update/reset the 'daily_counter' during the query (Ex: MyEventCounter.query.all() ) if the 'last_updated_at' was in the previous day? PS: Maybe something like a computed property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should use a property. It should be as easy as:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

@property
def counter(self):
    if self.last_updated_at.date() < dt.now().date():
        self.last_updated_at = dt.now()
        self.daily_counter = 0
        db.session.commit()

    return self.daily_counter
```

Comment: Interestingly, I came with a very similar looking code :)

Comment: If the answer is correct, I’d appreciate you marking it as such. :-)